# ExtJS GPL and Commercial license issues

Tags: extjs, licensing

We will develop one commercial software for one company, and this software will be sold to customers of the company. This software contains font-end JS/HTML based codes and back-end C++ codes. We want to use ExtJS4.2 to develop font-end module.

1. We will not modify ExtJS code itself and just use it for the library, but I don't know if extending ExtJS type/class will be treated as "modifying ExtJS".
2. If we **do not** want to make back-end codes open source, which license do we need?
3. If we have to use Commercial License, Could we first use GPLv3 to try the ExtJS for learning and training privately in company, and use Commercial license when we decide to release software and begin to charge?
4. If we have to use Commercial License, which kind of Commercial License do we need to buy? We have one team containing several people to develop font-end module.

Comment: "Could we first use GPLv3 to try the ExtJS for learning and training privately in company, and use Commercial license when we decide to release software and begin to charge?". Absolutely. GPL only limits you when you start distributing software (free of charge or not).

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494591/ext-js-licensing-options?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042580/question-regarding-the-extjs-license?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813123/usage-of-extjs-under-gpl-v3?rq=1

Comment: Actually, according to their FAQ: "No, the terms of our commercial license do not allow this. You must choose which license you wish to use (commercial, GPLv3, or OEM) at the beginning of your development lifecycle." https://www.sencha.com/store/licensing-faq

Comment: Licensing questions are belong to Programmers.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

"Could we first use GPLv3 to try the ExtJS for learning and training privately in company, and use Commercial license when we decide to release software and begin to charge?"

Not according to Sencha's own commercial license. See this section of http://www.sencha.com/legal/sencha-sdk-software-license-agreement

"The Open Source version of the Software (“GPL Version”) is licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public License versions 3.0 (“GPL”) and not under this Agreement. If You, or another third party, has, at any time, developed all (or any portions of) the Application(s) using the GPL Version, You may not combine such development work with the Software and must license such Application(s) (or any portions derived there from) under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 3, a copy of which is located at http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html."

Comment: From my point of view, that interpretations is quite wrong. You as the author of your own code can decide your own code license as long you don't depend on GPL3. So: when you switch from GPL to commercial ExtJS license, you just switch your own code license from GPL to you own, and 100% own license (except if the commercial license has a "pseudo-viral" clause). You, as author, can switch your licence whenever you want. And saying "If you once use GPL, your code never can change the licence" is simply false.

Comment: It's not an "interpretation", it's part of the sencha commercial software license agreement....a legal document. You don't get to apply common sense in contradiction to legal requirements.

Comment: GPL is not from Sencha... and one thing is a license of your code, and other thing are your rights about being  the author. Think about MySQL-MariaDB issues for a while as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think all your questions are answered [here](https://www.sencha.com/store/licensing-faq).